# grails 3.3 console plugin - no displayed response?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I just recreated an old app in Grails 3.3.0M2.  I already have an extensive 3.2.5 app running so I thought I knew what I was doing.  The problem is this - I can't get the grails console plugin to display its response to the web page.  If I execute the cmd "println '123'", I get just a ">>" output.  That is what I get for any command I run.  I can breakpoint the plugin and the eval output is trying to return "123", but it's not getting to the web page.  Any thoughts?  Plugin configured via "runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.0.8'".

Comment: Ok, I see the response is coming back as JSON and for some reason not displaying.  That is the problem; nothing that I can see wrong with the plugin or configuration.

Comment: Except the response Content-Type is text/html, whereas it should be application/json.

Comment: In Grails 3.2.5, using slightly older plugins, the console response comes back correctly as application/json.  As mentioned above, with the newer plugins the response has an incorrect Content-Type of text/html.

Comment: No, I don't think it's the plugin.  In both instances I can use the grails-console:2.0.8 plugin.  In 3.2.5, the response comes back as application/json, in 3.3.0.M2 it comes back at text/html.   I will have to look elsewhere to explain this.